# Running a custom command using execute_process() is skipping the arguments

Tags: cmake

**Problem**: Trying to run a command before my build process starts.

```
find_package(Python)
message("Running a specific command")
execute_process(COMMAND ${Python3_EXECUTABLE} ${SPECIFIC_DIR}/spec_file.py xxx)
message("Command execution: Successful")
```

And I'm ending up like this:

```
Running a specific command
Command Status: Successful
```

I couldn't see any output in the powershell window.
Am I making a mistake somewhere? Also I want to run this specific "build"(not cmake directly) at the beginning. This python file will perform another build which will generate the .lib's and .a's.
So that some libraries will be generated so that I can link to the parent repo's target.

Comment: As you don't get any output, then why do you think that `execute_process` **skips** its arguments? It could be that your command terminated errorneously. You may check the result of executed command using `RESULTS_VARIABLE` option for [execute_process](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/execute_process.html) command. You could also print (using `message` command) the actual strings which you pass to `execute_process`. Or you could use additional option `COMMAND_ECHO STDOUT`, so CMake will print actual command which it executes.